# how to extract specific part from long string

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a html source code having mobile numbers in it, i want to extract just phone numbers from that source code, each phone number have starting and ending flag, lets say
sample HTML code is,
every mobile number starts from 'phone=' and ends with % as shown in below,

```
b2e1d163b0b4dc6ebfa5&amp;t=s&amp;phone=95355036019918%40c.us&amp;i=1522996189"
```

how can i extract only phone numbers using php?

Comment: what u have tried so far?

Comment: That looks like a query string, you can use [`parse_str`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) to convert it to an array. Please don't try and do it with a regex.

Comment: What did you try and are ALL phone numbes have `phone=` before the number and do the phone numbers always have %40 behind the phone number? If you know what to look for `preg_match_all` can do that for you

Comment: yes starting and ending strings are the same for every phone number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php
function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
    $string = ' ' . $string;
    $ini = strpos($string, $start);
    if ($ini == 0) return '';
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string, $end, $ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string, $ini, $len);
}

$fullstring = 'b2e1d163b0b4dc6ebfa5&t=s&phone=95355036019918%40c.us&i=1522996189"';
$phone = get_string_between($fullstring, '&phone=', '%');

echo $phone;
```

**[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e00ffaa53e1d59153c0712438efadea27a7aabf3)**

if it is multiple

```
<?php
function getInbetweenStrings($start, $end, $str){
    $matches = array();
    $regex = "/$start([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)$end/";
    preg_match_all($regex, $str, $matches);
    return $matches[1];
}

$str = 'b2e1d163b0b4dc6ebfa5&t=s&phone=95355036019918%40c.us&i=1522996189"<style="color:red">b2e1d163b0b4dc6ebfa5&t=s&phone=111111111111111%40cb2e1d163b0b4dc6ebfa5&t=s&phone=222222222222%40c.us&i=1522996189".us&i=1522996189"';
$str_arr = getInbetweenStrings('&phone=', '%', $str);

print_r($str_arr);
```

**[Demo for Multiple](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8f8f4ec41b748186c55a9324e004a39072d05aaa)**

Comment: great, but its giving only one phone number, but there are hundreds of the phone numbers to be required to extract.

Comment: Show me example

Comment: b2e1d163b0b4dc6ebfa5&t=s&phone=95355036019918%40c.us&i=1522996189"<style='color:red'>b2e1d163b0b4dc6ebfa5&t=s&phone=111111111111111%40cb2e1d163b0b4dc6ebfa5&t=s&phone=222222222222%40c.us&i=1522996189".us&i=1522996189"

Comment: Check Answer updated @TasaddaqRana

Comment: 100% meets with my requirements, thank you siddartha esunuri

Answer (score 0):

This is a peasant way but it should do your job:

```
$string = "b2e1d163b0b4dc6ebfa5&t=s&phone=95355036019918%40c.us&i=1522996189";
$explode = explode('&phone=',$string);
$phone = explode('%', $explode[1]);
var_dump($phone[0]);
```